# Fixed column and row header for DataTable on Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I've build a table on Flutter Dart using `DataTable`. This table is very large, and I'm using both Vertical and Horizontal scrolling.
When scrolling I lose reference to columns, I need to know what is the column.

As example. On the screenshot i don't know what the numbers `20.0` and `25.0` on the means, unless I scroll to the top.

I've added a GIF example of what i want to achieve. (Using LibreOffice). I need fixed column name (first row).

Example of the table, while scrolling around the middle of the table:
[image: Table without header for reference]

Example of what i want to do:
[image: LibreOffice Calc Example]

Code sample for my table:

```dart
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: MyDataSet.getColumns(),
          rows: widget._data.map<DataRow>((row) => DataRow(
            onSelectChanged: (d) {
              setState(() {
                selectedRow = d ? row.hashCode : null;
              });
            },
            selected: row.hashCode == selectedRow,
            cells: MyDataSet.toDataCells(row)
          )).toList()
        )
      ),
    );
```

Missing code sample:

```dart
return columns.map<DataColumn>((name) => DataColumn(
      label: Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),)
    )).toList();
```

---

## Update (24/10/2019)

Current code works well if header name is the same size as cell content. Otherwise both sizes will be different.

[image: Different sizes]

---

## Update (21/02/2020)

People created a package to do that. :D

https://pub.dev/packages/table_sticky_headers

Image from pub.dev!
[image: Pub.dev example image.]

Comment: Let me know if I understood correctly: if you scroll vertically the entire first row should be fixed and if you scroll horizontally the entire first column should be fixed?

Comment: Exactly. On the screenshot above, there is no reference of what the column means (column header). And also there is no reference of what the row is about (row first column). On Excel and Google Calc this is called Freeze Header, a video example: https://youtu.be/dTpwj74hTfE

Comment: @PabloBarrera I added a GIF showing exactly what i'm trying to achieve. Also I've improved the explanation.

Comment: The GIF doesn't show an horizontal scroll, does it?

Comment: The example is incomplete. What I'm trying to do, if i scroll horizontally, the first row will scroll togehter. Always showing the column names (first row).

Comment: Okay, I think is what I understood. I let you know if I find a solution for this

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964352/6550011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the flutter package [**horizontal_data_table**](https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table)
A Flutter Widget that create a horizontal table with fixed column on left hand side.

```
dependencies:
  horizontal_data_table: ^2.5.0
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed the best solution in 2021. It fixes the problem if not being able to fix header without using fixed column sizes. I'll convert my app to this table and test.

Comment: yet another 3rd party lib!

Answer (score 21):

I could come up with a workaround using scroll controllers, looks like this: [Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DpPjujn9dWR1m8mn7N54vFdDt4NEc2fP)

Basically it's an horizontal scroll for the first row, a vertical scroll for the first column and a mixed horizontal and vertical scroll for the subtable. Then when you move the subtable, its controllers move the column and the row.

Here is a custom widget with an example of how to use it:

```
final _rowsCells = [
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8]
];
final _fixedColCells = [
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
];
final _fixedRowCells = [
  "Math",
  "Informatics",
  "Geography",
  "Physics",
  "Biology"
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: CustomDataTable(
      rowsCells: _rowsCells,
      fixedColCells: _fixedColCells,
      fixedRowCells: _fixedRowCells,
      cellBuilder: (data) {
        return Text('$data', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
      },
    ),
  );
}

class CustomDataTable<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T fixedCornerCell;
  final List<T> fixedColCells;
  final List<T> fixedRowCells;
  final List<List<T>> rowsCells;
  final Widget Function(T data) cellBuilder;
  final double fixedColWidth;
  final double cellWidth;
  final double cellHeight;
  final double cellMargin;
  final double cellSpacing;

  CustomDataTable({
    this.fixedCornerCell,
    this.fixedColCells,
    this.fixedRowCells,
    @required this.rowsCells,
    this.cellBuilder,
    this.fixedColWidth = 60.0,
    this.cellHeight = 56.0,
    this.cellWidth = 120.0,
    this.cellMargin = 10.0,
    this.cellSpacing = 10.0,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDataTableState();
}

class CustomDataTableState<T> extends State<CustomDataTable<T>> {
  final _columnController = ScrollController();
  final _rowController = ScrollController();
  final _subTableYController = ScrollController();
  final _subTableXController = ScrollController();

  Widget _buildChild(double width, T data) => SizedBox(
      width: width, child: widget.cellBuilder?.call(data) ?? Text('$data'));

  Widget _buildFixedCol() => widget.fixedColCells == null
      ? SizedBox.shrink()
      : Material(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child: DataTable(
              horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
              columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
              headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
              dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                    label: _buildChild(
                        widget.fixedColWidth, widget.fixedColCells.first))
              ],
              rows: widget.fixedColCells
                  .sublist(widget.fixedRowCells == null ? 1 : 0)
                  .map((c) => DataRow(
                      cells: [DataCell(_buildChild(widget.fixedColWidth, c))]))
                  .toList()),
        );

  Widget _buildFixedRow() => widget.fixedRowCells == null
      ? SizedBox.shrink()
      : Material(
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
          child: DataTable(
              horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
              columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
              headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
              dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
              columns: widget.fixedRowCells
                  .map((c) =>
                      DataColumn(label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
                  .toList(),
              rows: []),
        );

  Widget _buildSubTable() => Material(
      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      child: DataTable(
          horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
          columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
          headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          columns: widget.rowsCells.first
              .map((c) => DataColumn(label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
              .toList(),
          rows: widget.rowsCells
              .sublist(widget.fixedRowCells == null ? 1 : 0)
              .map((row) => DataRow(
                  cells: row
                      .map((c) => DataCell(_buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
                      .toList()))
              .toList()));

  Widget _buildCornerCell() =>
      widget.fixedColCells == null || widget.fixedRowCells == null
          ? SizedBox.shrink()
          : Material(
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: DataTable(
                  horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
                  columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
                  headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
                  dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                        label: _buildChild(
                            widget.fixedColWidth, widget.fixedCornerCell))
                  ],
                  rows: []),
            );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subTableXController.addListener(() {
      _rowController.jumpTo(_subTableXController.position.pixels);
    });
    _subTableYController.addListener(() {
      _columnController.jumpTo(_subTableYController.position.pixels);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _columnController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: _buildFixedCol(),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _subTableXController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _subTableYController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: _buildSubTable(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildCornerCell(),
            Flexible(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _rowController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: _buildFixedRow(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Since the first column, the first row and the subtable are independent, I had to create a `DataTable` for each one. And since `DataTable` has headers that can't be removed, the headers of the first column and the subtable are hidden by the first row.

Also, I had to make the first column and first row not manually scrollable because if you scroll them the subtable won't scroll.

This might not be the best solution, but at the moment doesn't seem to be another way to do it. You could try to improve this approach, maybe using `Table` or other widgets instead of `DataTable` at least you could avoid hiding the headers of the subtable and first column.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making this code work. Can you share the full code?

Comment: You should put all of this inside the state of a StatefulWidget, there's no more code.

Comment: It's missing totalRows and totalColumns initialization

Comment: Worked very well! Thank you! I'll try to clean, and build a re-usable component of it.

Comment: I'm having and error. If you run the code, but change "Cell" text to "Cell with lots of text" and you will see that the size are not the same.

Comment: I think there's a property to set the size in DataTable, since they're independent DataTables you may need to set their size equally. I'll edit my answer when I can check that.

Comment: Looking at [DataTable Code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/62674cee3d61b170bfba227c503953adeec4bc0a/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart) i've found out that the width is build using `tableColumns[displayColumnIndex] = const IntrinsicColumnWidth(flex: 1.0);`. On the end it uses: `return Table(
      columnWidths: tableColumns.asMap(),
      children: tableRows,
    );` to use the values on the internal Table object. But this property is not exposed.

Comment: The discussion was expanded to Github as well: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21165

Comment: I updated my answer with a CustomDataTable where you can set the information to fill the table and the width of the cells. I think with this you can get an idea of how to improve it.

Comment: Hi @PabloBarrera. First of all thanks for this answer, I have created the table from your code but I am getting null value at the leftmost corner cell. Do I need to create separate variable for corner cell like _rowsCells, _fixedColCells given in the above code? In the above video link the corner cell has value given "Corner" so where did you defined that value in your code?

Comment: If you're using the CustomDataTable widget you just need to specify the fixedCornerCell property. You can check the _buildCornerCell() method inside CustomDataTable.

Comment: @GustavoGarcia do you have a Github link where you made it work? I am getting a lot of errors.

Answer (score 10):

A few months back I had similar issue with limmited capabilities of stock DataTable and PaginatedDataTable2 widgets which didn't allow to fix the header. Eventually I took those widgets appart and created my own versions but with blackjack and fixed header row. Here's the plug-in on pub.dev:
https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2

The classes DataTable2 and PaginatedDataTable2 provide exactly the same APIs as the original versions.

**NOTE:** these one only implement sticky top rows, leftmost columns are not fixed/sticky

Comment: Amazing. Been looking for a fixed header solution that just flawlessly maps to the original datatable.  I've been avoiding the other solutions out there as they bring new unintuitive syntax and issues and I was about to hack into the datatable code but you already done the hard work. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Below Given [Pablo Barrera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11938462/pablo-barrera) answer is quite interesting, I have corrected and modified this answer with an enhanced feature, also it is easy to handle `DataTable` with fixed rows and columns. This `DataTable` you can customize as per your requirements.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataTablePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTablePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: CustomDataTable(
              fixedCornerCell: '',
              borderColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
              rowsCells: _rowsCells,
              fixedColCells: _fixedColCells,
              fixedRowCells: _fixedRowCells,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final _rowsCells = [
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8],
  [7, 8, 10, 8, 7],
  [10, 10, 9, 6, 6],
  [5, 4, 5, 7, 5],
  [9, 4, 1, 7, 8]
];
final _fixedColCells = [
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Pablo",
  "Gustavo",
  "John",
  "Jack",
];
final _fixedRowCells = [
  "Math",
  "Informatics",
  "Geography",
  "Physics",
  "Biology"
];

class CustomDataTable<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T fixedCornerCell;
  final List<T> fixedColCells;
  final List<T> fixedRowCells;
  final List<List<T>> rowsCells;
  final double fixedColWidth;
  final double cellWidth;
  final double cellHeight;
  final double cellMargin;
  final double cellSpacing;
  final Color borderColor;

  const CustomDataTable({
    super.key,
    required this.fixedCornerCell,
    required this.fixedColCells,
    required this.fixedRowCells,
    required this.rowsCells,
    this.fixedColWidth = 60.0,
    this.cellHeight = 56.0,
    this.cellWidth = 120.0,
    this.cellMargin = 10.0,
    this.cellSpacing = 10.0,
    required this.borderColor,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDataTableState();
}

class CustomDataTableState<T> extends State<CustomDataTable<T>> {
  final _columnController = ScrollController();
  final _rowController = ScrollController();
  final _subTableYController = ScrollController();
  final _subTableXController = ScrollController();

  Widget _buildChild(double width, T data) => SizedBox(
        width: width,
        child: Text(
          '$data',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      );

  TableBorder _buildBorder({
    bool top = false,
    bool left = false,
    bool right = false,
    bool bottom = false,
    bool verticalInside = false,
  }) {
    return TableBorder(
      top: top ? BorderSide(color: widget.borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
      left: left ? BorderSide(color: widget.borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
      right: right ? BorderSide(color: widget.borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
      bottom: bottom ? BorderSide(color: widget.borderColor) : BorderSide.none,
      verticalInside: verticalInside
          ? BorderSide(color: widget.borderColor)
          : BorderSide.none,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFixedCol() => DataTable(
      border: _buildBorder(right: true),
      horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
      columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
      headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
      dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
            label:
                _buildChild(widget.fixedColWidth, widget.fixedColCells.first))
      ],
      rows: widget.fixedColCells
          .map((c) =>
              DataRow(cells: [DataCell(_buildChild(widget.fixedColWidth, c))]))
          .toList());

  Widget _buildFixedRow() => DataTable(
        border: _buildBorder(verticalInside: true, bottom: true),
        horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
        columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
        headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
        dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
        columns: widget.fixedRowCells
            .map(
              (c) => DataColumn(
                label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        rows: const [],
      );

  Widget _buildSubTable() => Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: DataTable(
          border: _buildBorder(verticalInside: true),
          horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
          columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
          headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
          columns: widget.rowsCells.first
              .map((c) => DataColumn(label: _buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
              .toList(),
          rows: widget.rowsCells
              .map(
                (row) => DataRow(
                    cells: row
                        .map((c) => DataCell(_buildChild(widget.cellWidth, c)))
                        .toList()),
              )
              .toList()));

  Widget _buildCornerCell() => DataTable(
        border: _buildBorder(bottom: true, right: true),
        horizontalMargin: widget.cellMargin,
        columnSpacing: widget.cellSpacing,
        headingRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
        dataRowHeight: widget.cellHeight,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
            label: _buildChild(
              widget.fixedColWidth,
              widget.fixedCornerCell,
            ),
          )
        ],
        rows: const [],
      );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _subTableXController.addListener(() {
      _rowController.jumpTo(_subTableXController.position.pixels);
    });
    _subTableYController.addListener(() {
      _columnController.jumpTo(_subTableYController.position.pixels);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: widget.borderColor),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              _buildCornerCell(),
              Flexible(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _rowController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: _buildFixedRow(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _columnController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: _buildFixedCol(),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _subTableXController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _subTableYController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: _buildSubTable(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]