# Scrollable table with fixed first row and fixed first column in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a table that fixes the first row to stay on the visible layout while scrolling vertically but scrolls horizontally normally and the some for first column.

Notification and gesture detectors

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FixedColumn {
  String valueColumn;
  FixedColumn({this.valueColumn});
}

List<FixedColumn> fixedColumn = [
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y1'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y2'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y3'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y4'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y5'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y6'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y7'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y8'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y9'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y10'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y11'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y12'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y13'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y14'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y15'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y16'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y17'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y18'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y19'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y20'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y21'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y22'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y23'),
  FixedColumn(valueColumn: 'Y24'),

];

class FixedRow {
  String valueRow;
  FixedRow({this.valueRow});
}

List<FixedRow> fixedRow = [
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X1'),
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X2'),
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X3'),
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X4'),
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X5'),
  FixedRow(valueRow: 'X6'),

];

class Content {
  String vC1;
  String vC2;
  String vC3;
  String vC4;
  String vC5;
  String vC6;

  Content({this.vC1, this.vC2, this.vC3, this.vC4, this.vC5, this.vC6});
}

List<Content> valueContent = [
  Content(vC1: 'FIRST', vC2: '2z', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: 
'6'),
  Content(vC1: '2', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '3', vC2: '2', vC3: '3z', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '4', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '5', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '6', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4z', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '7', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '8', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '9', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5z', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '10', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '11', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '12', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6z'),
  Content(vC1: '13', vC2: '2z', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '14', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '15', vC2: '2', vC3: '3z', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '16', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '17', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '18', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4z', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '19', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '20', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '21', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5z', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '22', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '23', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: '6'),
  Content(vC1: '24', vC2: '2', vC3: '3', vC4: '4', vC5: '5', vC6: 'LAST'),
];

class PlayGround extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayGroundState createState() => _PlayGroundState();
}
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

class _PlayGroundState extends State<PlayGround> {
  double viewOffSet = 0.0;

  changePosition(ScrollNotification notification) {
    setState(() {
      if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
        viewOffSet = viewOffSet + notification.scrollDelta;
        controller.jumpTo(viewOffSet);
      }
    });
  }
  double widthVal = 80.0;
  double heightVal = 30.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0F8FF),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SCROLLABLE TABLE')),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  controller: controller,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: heightVal,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      controller: controller,
                      itemCount: fixedRow.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Color(0xFF03A9F4),
                            width: widthVal,
                            height: heightVal,
                            child: Text(
                              fixedRow[index].valueRow,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(flex:1,
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(flex:1,
                        child: Container(
                          height: heightVal*fixedColumn.length,
                          width: widthVal,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            controller: controller,
                              itemCount: fixedColumn.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    color: Color(0xFF03A9F4),
                                    height: heightVal,
                                    width: widthVal,
                                    child: Text(fixedColumn[index].valueColumn,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        )));
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(flex:4,
                        child: NotificationListener(
    onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
                            changePosition(notification);
                            return;
                          },
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Container(

                              width: widthVal*fixedRow.length,
                              child:  ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                itemCount: valueContent.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              width: widthVal,
                                              height: heightVal,
                                              child: Text(
                                                  valueContent[index].vC1)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          width: widthVal,
                                          height: heightVal,
                                          child: Text(
                                              valueContent[index].vC2)),
                                      Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          width: widthVal,
                                          height: heightVal,
                                          child: Text(
                                              valueContent[index].vC3)),
                                      Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          width: widthVal,
                                          height: heightVal,
                                          child: Text(
                                              valueContent[index].vC4)),
                                      Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          width: widthVal,
                                          height: heightVal,
                                          child: Text(
                                              valueContent[index].vC5)),
                                      Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          width: widthVal,
                                          height: heightVal,
                                          child: Text(
                                              valueContent[index].vC6)),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is functioning but not correctly. First row continue scrolling while scrolling vertically and the same for the column the tries to scroll as the table scrolls horizontally. Is there any way to recognize and pass to the parent if it is scrolling vertically or only horizontally?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398787/fixed-header-for-datatable-on-flutter-dart (possible duplicate)

Comment: Thank you! that was beautiful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed header for DataTable on Flutter Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398787/fixed-header-for-datatable-on-flutter-dart)

Comment: @PabloBarrera you need to use flag (bottom of post) > duplicate for possible duplicate questions.

Comment: That's what I did, and my last comment was automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [table_sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/table_sticky_headers) plugin to lock specific columns/row on your table widgets.

[image]