# Flutter Fixed/Sticky LEFT and RIGHT columns and top rows for DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing Flutter App using data table.

In that I want the data table can keep the top rows, and left and right columns when scrolling.

That means only the center part of columns can be scroll when scrolling horizontally.

So is there any way to freeze headers, left columns and right columns?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here i used [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) as per your requirement.

i make one list (headerList) for header Row in DataTable and after remove first and last element from this list and store in another list (centerHeader) for central scrolleble DataTable .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyDataTable(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDataTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDataTable({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDataTable> createState() => _MyDataTableState();
}

class _MyDataTableState extends State<MyDataTable> {
  List<String> headerList = [
    "SR.",
    "Name",
    "Math",
    "Science",
    "English",
    "Biology",
    "Physics",
    "Computer",
    "Total",
    "Grade"
  ];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowData = [
    {
      "name": "Sahil",
      "mark": [90, 80, 85, 75, 65, 78],
      "total": 473,
      "grade": "A",
    },
    {
      "name": "Rohit",
      "mark": [89, 79, 84, 74, 64, 77],
      "total": 467,
      "grade": "A",
    },
    {
      "name": "Siddharth",
      "mark": [85, 95, 98, 97, 95, 96],
      "total": 566,
      "grade": "A+",
    },
  ];

  late List<String> centerHeader;
  // make this list for central table and this will scrollable
  // and this will get value in initState()

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // get value from main list
    centerHeader = List.from(headerList);

    // remove first element for not scrolling -> remove "SR." from headerList
    centerHeader.removeAt(0);

    // remove last element for not scrolling -> remove "Grade" from headerList
    centerHeader.removeAt(centerHeader.length - 1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Student Result"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // first table -> will give Serial number and count
                DataTable(
                  horizontalMargin: 10,
                  headingRowHeight: 45,
                  headingRowColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade100),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  dataRowHeight: 40,
                  columnSpacing: 8,
                  dividerThickness: 0,
                  border: TableBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        headerList[0],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  rows: rowData.map(
                    (e) {
                      final i = rowData.indexOf(e);
                      return DataRow(
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text("${1 + i}"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                ),

                // cental DataTable which will scrolling
                // here use centerHeader (List)
                // Flexible -> SingleChildScrollView for scrolling purpose
                Flexible(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: DataTable(
                      horizontalMargin: 10,
                      headingRowHeight: 45,
                      headingRowColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade100),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      dataRowHeight: 40,
                      columnSpacing: 8,
                      dividerThickness: 0,
                      border: TableBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                      columns: centerHeader.map(
                        (e) {
                          return DataColumn(
                            label: Text(e),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                      rows: rowData.map(
                        (e) {
                          return DataRow(
                            cells: [
                              DataCell(
                                Text(e['name']),
                              ),
                              ...e['mark']
                                  .map(
                                    (m) => DataCell(
                                      Text("$m"),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  .toList(),
                              DataCell(
                                Text("${e['total']}"),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Last(third) DataTable
                DataTable(
                  horizontalMargin: 10,
                  headingRowHeight: 45,
                  headingRowColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade100),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  dataRowHeight: 40,
                  columnSpacing: 8,
                  dividerThickness: 0,
                  border: TableBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(headerList.last),
                    )
                  ],
                  rows: rowData.map(
                    (e) {
                      return DataRow(
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text(
                              e['grade'],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

run this code!

Hope this will help you!

Thank You!

Comment: it looks good. but when rows data is growing, It cant be scroll vertically.

any fix? Thanks

Comment: I add singleChildScrollView before padding widget, it can scroll vertically but the top header row is not sticky. 

any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Here you will get more details [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398787/fixed-column-and-row-header-for-datatable-on-flutter-dart)