# How to make the Flutter DataTable header as sticky while its content is scrollable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-table

I am trying to make a flutter DataTable's header fixed while scrolling.
I want only the content to scroll Scrolling behavior referenced from NG-Zorro Table.

[image]

I tried using [table_sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/table_sticky_headers).
But is there any way to achieve this natively without using any package?

As I am using DataTable widget. i need the header(DataColumn) to be fixed, and the content(DataRow) should be scrollable, but i am not able to use the scrollable widget inside the   cells. so i am using SingleChildScroolView outside the DataTable Widget.

I have attached the sample code below to work on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExample({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: CheckboxTheme(
                    data: CheckboxThemeData(
                      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                        (_) =>
                            const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blueGrey[25]),
                      checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Colors.blueGrey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: DataTable(
                      columnSpacing: 12,
                      headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                          (states) => Colors.grey[50]),
                      dataRowHeight: 60,
                      checkboxHorizontalMargin: 5,
                      showCheckboxColumn: true,
                      horizontalMargin: 6,
                      columns: [
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              'header 1',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'heder 2',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: Colors.grey[500],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'header 3',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: Colors.grey[500],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              'header 4',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: [
                        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                          DataRow(
                            color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                              if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                                return Colors.transparent;
                              }
                              return Colors.transparent;
                            }),
                            cells: [
                              DataCell(
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "data 1",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.grey[900],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  "data 2",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  "data 3",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  "data 4",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed column and row header for DataTable on Flutter Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398787/fixed-column-and-row-header-for-datatable-on-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with DataTable2 , just install the package
here is the link : https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2
you just have to do minor changes like  and then you have to use the property  -
fixedTopRows  to fix the rows let's say you want to freezed the header or 1st row so put it like, Also DataTable2 provide you more add on features over the DataTable  -

```
 DataTable2(
                  fixedColumnsColor: context
                      .utils.colorUtils.tableBorderColor
                      .withOpacity(0.2),
                  fixedTopRows: 1,
                  fixedCornerColor:
                      context.utils.colorUtils.tableBorderColor,
                  border: TableBorder(
                    top: BorderSide(
                        color: context.utils.colorUtils.tableBorderColor),
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: context.utils.colorUtils.tableBorderColor),
                  ),
                  scrollController: ScrollController(),
                  fixedLeftColumns: 1,
                  headingRowDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: context.utils.colorUtils.tableBorderColor,
                  ),
                  horizontalScrollController: ScrollController(),
                  minWidth: 456.w,
                  dividerThickness: 0.6,
                  horizontalMargin: 16.w,
                  dataTextStyle: poppinsRegular.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 12.sp,
                    color:Colors.black,
                  ),
                  headingRowHeight: context.height * 0.054,
                  dataRowHeight: context.height * 0.056,
                  headingTextStyle: poppinsMedium.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 12.sp,
                    color: context.utils.colorUtils.primaryTextColor,
                  ),
                  columns: [],
                  rows: [],
                ),
```